# Buggy jQuery animate code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I adapted some code I had for animating the color of text for animating the colour of the background. But now the code is a little buggy. In Chrome the background changes to white on the first hover over, and in all browsers it just takes ages to load (I have the plugins stored on the server if that makes a difference), so you have to wait a few seconds to get the effect. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".olli").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#e8e5e2" }, 500);
    },function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#dbd6d0" }, 500);
    }); 
});
```

The .olli class comes from this:

```
$("#ulnav > li").addClass("olli");
```

Comment: The ordinary `animate` can't animate colors, you can use separate plugin for this: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

Comment: @Shadow: OP has jQueryUI loaded. This lets you animate colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an initial color set for the background. Either set it in CSS to the "off" color, or do this:

```
$(".olli").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#e8e5e2" }, 500);
},function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#dbd6d0" }, 500);
}).css({ backgroundColor: "#dbd6d0" });
```

or

```
.olli {
    background-color: "#dbd6d0";
}
```

The computed style (in Chrome anyway) is `background-color:transparent`, so a starting point is needed for the animation, and jQueryUI must use `#FFF`.

To get around the slow loading issue, remove your `<script>` tags from the `<head>` and place them just *above* the *analytics* code (right after the `#content` section), and get rid of the `.ready()` call.

---

**EDIT:**

You may want to do this when removing the `.ready()` call. Prevents creation of global variables (if you have any variables).

```
(function( $ ) {

    $(".olli").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#e8e5e2" }, 500);
    },function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#dbd6d0" }, 500);
    }).css({ backgroundColor: "#dbd6d0" }); 

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: The problem is I think the server generates the analytic code, so I can't place the script files above it. Regarding removing the .ready() call, can you show me what it would look like? Thanks for your help

Comment: Got it working, moved the scripts to the end of the body section, and remove the whole .ready line. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Jake: Are you saying that you can only place `<script>` files in the `<head>`? If the server is generating the analytics code, then you should just be able to place your `<script>` files at the end of your content. With regard to how it would look without `.ready()`, it would be just like the code in my answer. Notice that I excluded `$(document).ready(function() {   });`. Or better, give it its own scope. I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove this lines of code from your site.

```
<!-- www.000webhost.com Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://www.hosting24.com/"><img src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php" alt="web hosting" /></a></noscript>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

My Browser says me, that he could not load the count.php-file. Therefore your JS-Code doesn't work 'cause your `$(document).ready(function() {` is not true.

Comment: I can't do anything about that :/ it's not in my local files so it must the free web hosting. Is that what is taking it so long to load?

Comment: Yes! Remove the `$(document).ready(function() {` - clause to test it. But i'm totally sure.

Comment: I copied your HTML-Code and removed the Analytics Code. And it works well! http://osnaware.de/stacktest/

Comment: thanks for removing the analytics code, but it's the free webhosting I use that adds it. Guess I'll have to change the hosting soon. Thanks for all your help :D